# while trying to save record into Oracle 10g using java Swing the program terminates without executing

Tags: java, oracle, swing

Hi, I'm trying to save the record into Oracle 10g using the Java swing program. But when I run the program it is immediately terminated

```
import java.awt.event.*;

import java.sql.*;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
class Insert extends JFrame implements ActionListener
 {

JLabel label,label1,label2,label3,label4,label5;
JTextField tf1,tf2,tf3,tf4,tf5;
JButton btn;
Connection con;

Insert()
{
    super("Inserting employee records");

        label1 = new JLabel("empID:");

        label1.setBounds(20,20,100,20);

        tf1 = new JTextField(50);

        tf1.setBounds(130, 120, 200, 20);

        label2 = new JLabel("employeeName:");

        label2.setBounds(20, 150, 100, 20);

        tf2 = new JTextField(100);

        tf2.setBounds(130, 150, 200, 20);

        label3 = new JLabel("Gender:");

        label3.setBounds(20, 180, 100, 20);

        tf3 = new JTextField(50);

        tf3.setBounds(130, 180, 200, 20);

        label4 = new JLabel("DOB:");

        label4.setBounds(20, 210, 100, 20);

        tf4 = new JTextField(50);

        tf4.setBounds(130, 210, 100, 20);

        label5 = new JLabel("DOJ");

        label5.setBounds(130, 240, 100, 20);

        tf5 = new JTextField(50);

        tf5.setBounds(130,270,100,20);

        btn = new JButton("Submit");

        btn.setBounds(130, 300, 100, 20);

        btn.addActionListener(this);

        add(label1);
        add(tf1);
        add(label2);
        add(tf2);
        add(label3);
        add(tf3);
        add(label4);
        add(tf4);
        add(label5);
        add(tf5);
        add(btn);

        tf1.setEditable(false);
        tf5.setEditable(false);

}



public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
{
    String id = tf1.getText();
    String name = tf2.getText();
    String gender = tf3.getText();
    String dob = tf4.getText();


try
{
    String url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE";
    String u="ems2";
    String p="ems2";
    Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
    con=DriverManager.getConnection(url,u,p);


    PreparedStatement st = con.prepareStatement("insert into employee"+"(emp_id,"+"employeename,"+"gender,"+"dob,"+"doj)"+"values(?,?,?,?,?)");
    st.setString(1, id);
    st.setString(2,name);
    st.setString(3,gender);
    st.setString(4, dob);
    st.executeUpdate();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Data is successfully inserted into database");
    con.close();

}

catch(Exception ex)
{
    System.out.println(ex);
}
}
public static void main(String [] args)
{
    new  Insert();
}
}e
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are not showing you insert `JFrame`. try to do:

```
new Insert().setVisible(true);
```

Comment: Hi thanks it worked partially, but when i maximize nothing is displaying except the submit button.please help

Comment: in your constructor, add `setLayout(null);` after super and `setSize(500, 400);` at the last line.